# Vaadin what to add for version-control

Tags: svn, version-control, vaadin, vaadin14

we are using Vaadin 14. Which folders in the project should we commit to the Version-Control?
The folder node_modules is very large which is very time consuming, should we commit this?

Comment: do not, I repeat, do NOT add node_modules to git

Comment: Can you pls tell me which foulders i schouldn't add too

Comment: Please add your project structure, the build tool your use, how node is setup (via the build tool?  manual install?) etc.  In general i'd not check in any files, your buildtool/plugins/vaadin-dev-server installs (e.g. node, node_modules, package*, webconfig*) as those files are supposed to be generated anyway.

Comment: vaadin uses npm only since version 14. I changed your question so its clear you are talking about V14, not 10+. If that was wrong, feel free to roll back my edits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `node_modules` directory **should not** be added to version control!
- `package.json` and `package-lock.json` keep track of npm packages and pin their versions. You may want to add these to version control, in particular, if you added any local package directly with npm.
- `webpack.config.js` is webpack configuration. You can add custom webpack configuration to this file. You may want to add these to version control.
- `webpack.generated.js` is auto-generated webpack configuration imported by `webpack.config.js`. **Do not** add to version control, as it is always overwritten by `vaadin-maven-plugin` during execution of the `prepare-frontend` goal.

See [Build and Maintain a V14 project](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/v14-migration/v14-migration-guide.html#6-build-and-maintain-the-v14-project) for more info.